# Gzip compression through webpack not happening , what's missing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have noticed compression difference between manual webpack configuration and create-react-app for same application/code base,create-react-app configuration compression apparently is gzip because of which final bundle size is way less than manual configuration of webpack ,

So I also tried using CompressionPlugin but it seems not working as expected, what could be missing from webpack configuration

```js
const common = require("./webpack.common");
const path = require("path");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const globImporter = require('node-sass-glob-importer');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: "production",
    output: {
        filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
                    { loader: 'css-loader' },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            plugins: () => [require('autoprefixer')({
                                'overrideBrowserslist': ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions']
                            })],
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader', options: {
                            sassOptions: {
                                importer: globImporter()
                            }
                        }
                    }]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "./src/css/[name].[contentHash].css"
    },
        new CompressionPlugin({
            algorithm: 'gzip'
        }),
    ), new CleanWebpackPlugin()
    ]

})
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is the half way of the process. now you need to tell express to handle those gzip files. for this you need to install

```
npm i express-static-gzip
```

then in your server.js

```
const expressStaticGzip = require("express-static-gzip");
server.use(expressStaticGzip("dist")); //make sure you use this middleware on top of the other middlewares otherwise it will not work.
```